# External HDD not recognized on one computer

Tags: windows-10, usb, external-hard-drive

**issue**

I have a 3.5" HDD that I put in a USB enclosure (powered by its own brick). It works great on my laptop, but not on my Windows 10 desktop computer.

The HDD LED blinks red for a bit and the green power supply LED is on.

**What I tried**

Downloading drivers for mass storage device, re-installing / updating from the device manager, plugging it into another device port (keyboard).

The enclosure:

[image: my adapter case]

**updated to answer questions**

HDD model : ST 1000DM003 (Seagate Barracuda)

Laptop MB : [ Manufacturer : ASUSTek COMPUTER INC., Product : K55VD ]

Desktop MB : [ Manfacturer : ASUSTek ..., Product : Z97-P ]

is the USB port of the desktop you're plugging it in a 2.0 or 3.0 one? 3.0 (3.0 Intel(R) eXtensible

As for the instance ID and Hardware ID I don't know how to do that

Comment: Also, it looks your `Caps Lock` and/or `Shift` keys aren't working, if they were, you may have taken some effort in your post and used capital letters! I suggest you edit your question, questions which are well formatted and look like the poster made even a little effort usually get better responses!

Comment: Just a random guess, but, maybe your case uses USB 3 and your desktop USB port is USB 2?

Comment: the hdd box is usb 2.0 and i tried on both usb 3.0 & 2.0 but still nothing

Comment: Does the adapter come with two or one USB cables? Are you plugging it in to the Front USB ports on desktop? What happens when you plug in any usual USB pen drive to the same port? Is it detected and working fine therein? With HDD plugged in what does Device Manager show under USB devices?

Comment: the adapter have 1 electricity output and 1 usb output. i tried plugging it in the front and back usb ports of the pc but nothing. i plugged my phone (android) to the PC and it worked fine.

Comment: Do you get any indication on the adapter/HDD case, may be a blinking LED or something that could be indicating that the device may not be receiving adequate power? Try plugging in Data USB cable  in 2.0 port & auxiliary power in USB 3 port and check as well.

Comment: the hdd LED blings red for a bit and the power supply (not a usb auxliary power) is green. I added a pic to my adapter.

Comment: Can you post the model number of the drive?

Comment: do you mean the hdd or the case?

Comment: Does any new disk shows up in the Windows Device Management when you plug it in?

Comment: only the unrecognized the device driver shows up

Comment: What do the device properties of that "unrecognized device" say? Specifically, I'm interested in Device Instance ID/Hardware IDs.

Comment: Besides that, what are the models of the drive enclosure, hard disk, your laptop and your desktop motherboard? And, is the USB port of the desktop you're plugging it in (as seen in Device Manager, select View->Devices by Connection) a 2.0 or 3.0 one? I suspect there's a USB 2.0 vs 3.0 clash here somewhere.

Comment: updated the post to meet with what you asked